# Training a classifier on Human pose estimation

Tags: python, image-processing, conv-neural-network

Project description-I am planning to do a project in which I have to recognize various human actions such as yawning,sleeping,walking,etc.To do this I need features on human poses which can be done with human pose estimation. After training the model on human pose estimation I want to save those features and then train a classifier model on top of that to classify those actions. But I am not sure whether it is possible.If it is,how can I save the features.Also is it possible to train my own dataset to recognize some other uncommon actions(sleeping on the chair,etc). Any guide would be much helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Just use PoseNet.

Easiest way with JavaScript and Google hosting: https://js.tensorflow.org/

Then transfer learning to train your custom features.

Comment: how can I label the dataset for that.Where can I get pre-trained model for posenet?

Comment: Just Google with the framework you care about. TensorFlow first result was: https://github.com/kentsommer/tensorflow-posenet - but there are Keras, PyTorch and other implementations also.

Comment: @SamuelMarks this PoseNet you found on Google is for camera pose estimation, not human pose. There are 2 "PoseNet"s...

Comment: Are you sure that it possible to retrain the posenet model on js.tensorflow? https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs/issues/1418